# Assigning values from one structure to a dynamic structure in ABAP

Tags: dynamic, structure, abap

I have two structures: one is static, one dynamic. The static structure has four fields with names A B C D. The dynamic structure has two fields A1 and B1 for example, which are of the same type as A and B but do not have the same name. How can I assign the values from my static structure A and B to A1 and B2. Problem is: I don't know before runime if my A1 and B1 is called A1 or A2 etc.

Thanks for your help

Comment: So what do you know? Again, please provide a MWE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your ABAP version is over 7.5. You can use [CL_ABAP_CORRESPONDING](https://blogs.sap.com/2016/10/21/abap-news-release-7.51-cl_abap_corresponding-completed/)

```
types:
begin of test_1,
  a type bukrs,
  b type waers,
  c type string,
end of test_1.

types:
begin of test_2,
  g type bukrs,
  f type waers,
end of test_2.

data:
lo_struct_descr type ref to cl_abap_structdescr,
ls_test1        type test_1,
ls_test2        type test_2.

ls_test1 = value #( a = '0001' b = 'EUR' c = 'TEST').

lo_struct_descr ?= cl_abap_structdescr=>describe_by_data( p_data =  ls_test1  ).

data(lt_component_test1) = lo_struct_descr->get_components( ).

lo_struct_descr ?= cl_abap_structdescr=>describe_by_data( p_data =  ls_test2  ).

data(lt_component_test2) = lo_struct_descr->get_components( ).

read table lt_component_test2 with key type = lt_component_test1[ name = 'A']-type
  into data(ls_component_a).

read table lt_component_test2 with key type = lt_component_test1[ name = 'B']-type
  into data(ls_component_b).


try.
  data(mapper) =
    cl_abap_corresponding=>create(
      source      = ls_test1
      destination = ls_test2
      mapping     = value cl_abap_corresponding=>mapping_table(
        ( level = 0 kind = 1 srcname = 'A' dstname = ls_component_a-name )
        ( level = 0 kind = 1 srcname = 'B' dstname = ls_component_b-name )
      ) ).

  mapper->execute( exporting source      = ls_test1
                   changing  destination = ls_test2 ).
catch cx_corr_dyn_error into data(exc).
  cl_demo_output=>display( exc->get_text( ) ).
endtry.
```

If not, just use old `assign` statement.

```
assign component ls_component_a-name of structure ls_test2 to field-symbol(<lv_value>).
<lv_value> = ls_test1-a.

assign component ls_component_b-name of structure ls_test2 to <lv_value>.
<lv_value> = ls_test1-b.
```

Comment: Hi Allen, thanks for the help, but I'm not sure yet about your second part. I don't know how much components my dynamic strcture will have. in your example you have four different structures? ls_component_a / b ls_test2 and lv_value (the field symbol).

Comment: how much component of your dynamic structure is got from cl_abap_structdescr, you can describe everything using RTTS https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=42965

Comment: I just give this example to use ls_test2 as target structure. Actually i didn't use any component information from test_2. So it applies the same to your dynamic structure.

Comment: @ImperiousPerfect, if you don't know the number of fields in your dynamic structure, don't know their names, then what criterion are you going to use during the assignment? Type similarity?

Comment: @Suncatcher. Yes, type similarity. I solved the problem with Allens help. I thought it was more complex than it actually was. I used Allen's second solution with field symbols and Assigning

Comment: @ImperiousPerfect please mark all your questions as answered if it solves your problem. Thank you!